# Is there a way to contact an editor of my answer?

Tags: support

I answered a question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27873/can-anyone-tell-me-how-this-shelf-was-hung) and was intending to edit in an image when I had the >=10 reputation to do so.  (I've since learnt I could have included links in the answer, and someone else could have edited them in.)

In the meantime, someone else has kindly edited an image into my answer.  This is great... but now that I have the reputation to post images, I'd like to replace it with an image I took myself, which I think is better because it is the exact product I'm talking about, and the image shows my hand for scale.

But: I'd like to explain this to the person that edited the current image in.  I can't seem to do this as a comment on the answer.  Is there another way to contact this editor?

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to contact the editor.

Just edit your new image in.

It's unlikely that they'll notice the edit and even if they do they won't be upset that you changed the image for a better one.

Answer (score 5):

If you think it's necessary, you can include a description of why you're editing the post in the "Edit Summary" section. The site is more like a wiki and Q&A site mashup, content is frequently improved by other users, and changes are encouraged. Adding photos to posts for users that don't have enough rep is a common practice. We do it to help you while you're moving up the privileges ladder, and to help others that may see your post later. So if you have a better photo, by all means, add it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a comment to your question beginning with @author with the explanation - it will pop up in his inbox. This should be enough.
And you can delete the comment after some time if it was not needed any more.